# Creating a state machine in python

Tags: python, state-machine

I have created various simple 2 dimensional games in python before and because they were simple, I did not need to create such a thing. But I now need it due to needing to go back and fourth. 
To go forward though, I need some sort of direction...

I am around 200 lines into a new game and I haven't started on the actual game, its currently all dealing with the window, events and state's

```
### state machine

def run:
  #~setup window

  # Current state
  state = menu()

  running = True
  while running:
    #~event handler

    returns = state.update(events)
    if returns == "playgame":
      state = game()
    state.draw(window)
#menu state
class menu:
  def __init__(self):
    #~define vars for the menu (buttons, etc...)
    self.clickables = [] # filled with gui etc..
    self.image = image() # image of the menu

  def update(self, events):
    for event in events: # go through events
      for clickable in self.clickables: # go through clickables
        if clickable.testClicked(event.pos) != False: # Returns if clicked
          return clickable.testClicked(event.pos)

  def draw(self, window):
    self.image.draw(window)
#game state
class game(menu): # Exactly the same as menu (just used as example)
  def __init__(self):
    super(menu).__init__()
#gui button
class button: # Extremely shortened for example use
  def __init__(self, do): # do is a string 
    self.whenClickedDo = do

  def testClicked(self, mousePos):
    if mousePos in self.myRect: # myRect is the area of the button (Example!)
      return self.whenClickedDo
    return False
```

This above example was completely rushed but the question I ponder is... What is a better way to achieve this, or is the above an achievable/smart way to do things?

TLDR; A function "run" has a value "state" which can return a value which would be used to change itself into a different state. Is that a reasonable way to make a state machine?

Comment: so just to clarify (I'm having a slow day) are you after advice on states for the game? E.G. a 'main menu' state, a 'game playing' state etc etc?

Comment: @RichSmith No... I would like to know if returning a new state from the current states update function is preferred by the majority of the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a simple game engine in C++ and used a screen based system. I'll try and write a simple version in python for you now. The idea is that each part of the game is a different screen. So the main menu, is a screen, there is a gameplay screen (where all the action takes place), there might be an options screen for the user to change the settings etc etc. These are all managed by a screen list, each screen has a position in the list, and you can switch between screens depending on game events. So if the main menu screen is active, when the user clicks the 'play' button, the gameplay screen is now loaded.

I cant think of the top of my head exactly how I'd port it to python but this should give you somewhere to start at least.

So a screen would be a class something like this:

```
class Screen:

    # you can have objects in the screen as variables of the class here
    # e.g self.player = None

    def onEntry(self):
        # here you would init the assets for your screen
        # this could be the interface, sprites etc
        # e.g self.player = Player()

    def onExit(self):
        # do any clean up
        # maybe save player data if this is a gameplay screen
        # e.g self.player.save()

    def update(self):
        # main loop for this screen
        # e.g self.player.update()
```

Each specific Screen for your game would inherit from the Screen class and implement those functions with custom logic for that screen. Then the screen list would basically just be a list of these custom Screen classes. Your game would just flip between these Screens.

Comment: II believe you have roughly the same idea. Would you agree that this is one of the best ways to go with?
I use the "Screen" idea but without a template.

Comment: @AUFakie yeah I really like this approach, it keeps the game states and their logic quite separate from eachother, it also makes adding new functionality really straightforward